# Restructure documents: Is this possible?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":  ObjectId(...),
   "recorded": ISODate("2018-05-05T11:05:32.000"),
   "devices": [
       {
           "id": "KSA2",
           "temp": 32,
           "ttl": 10
       },
       {
           "id": "KSA24",
           "temp": 28,
           "ttl": 10
       }       
   ]  
}
{
   "_id":  ObjectId(...),
   "recorded": ISODate("2018-05-05T18:23:45.000"),
   "devices": [
       {
           "id": "KSA2",
           "temp": 31,
           "ttl": 10
       },
       {
           "id": "KSA24",
           "temp": 16,
           "ttl": 10
       }       
   ]  
}
```

What I need to do is to transform this into a document by device:

```
{
    "Devices": [
        {
            "id": "KSA2",
            "observations": [
                {
                    "time":ISODate("2018-05-05T11:05:32.000"),
                    "temp":32,
                    "ttl":10
                }
                {
                    "time":ISODate("2018-05-05T18:23:45.000"),
                    "temp":31,
                    "ttl":10
                }
            ]


        },
        {
            "id":"KSA24",
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this possible to do "within" mongodb using the aggregation framework or do I need to do this on the outside with Python or something similiar?

Comment: It will be a little hectic to achieve this within mongodb, i suggest you to use PyMongo (Python) to achieve this task. It will be easy to achieve it using PyMongo.

Comment: a little hectic, really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following aggregagtion on your collection :

```
db['myCollection'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$devices",

            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
            _id : "$devices.id",
            observations : {$push : 
              {
                time : "$recorded",
                temp:"$devices.temp",
                ttl:"$devices.ttl"}
              }
            }
        },
        {
            $out: "devices"
        },
    ],
);
```

Stages used :

- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) : create one document per devices element.
- [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) : group by device id, pushing custom sub-documents to bservation array.
- [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) : output the result to a new collection, here 'devices'.

This will output, in devices collection :

```
db['devices'].find();
{ 
    "_id" : "KSA24", 
    "observations" : [
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-05T13:05:32.000+0200"), 
            "temp" : 28.0, 
            "ttl" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-05T20:23:45.000+0200"), 
            "temp" : 16.0, 
            "ttl" : 10.0
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "KSA2", 
    "observations" : [
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-05T13:05:32.000+0200"), 
            "temp" : 32.0, 
            "ttl" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2018-05-05T20:23:45.000+0200"), 
            "temp" : 31.0, 
            "ttl" : 10.0
        }
    ]
}
```

After that, use new devices collection, or rename it to your old name.

Comment: Thank you! This is EXACTLY what I needed!